# How apply a JS function when some variables names contain same text?

Tags: javascript, json-ld

I have some variables in GTM (json-ld script) named « product-price-item-1», « product-price-item-2», «product-price-item-3»…

For each I need to apply a function

```
function(){
var price = {{product-price-item-1}};
var getPrice = price.replace(/[^0-9\,]+/g, "");
var trueprice = getPrice.replace(",", ".");
return trueprice;
}
```

How apply the function to all variables names contain « product-price-item» ?

Comment: `var element = {{product-price-item-1}};` this is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I’m not familiar with Javascript. Correct Update?

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! Whatever a json-ld script is. `{{product-price-item-1}}` is most probably a string as a Jekyll or other templating language variable, or maybe just a mistake :) Give us more context please.

Comment: Happy to be there!!!  It’s GTM variables ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to go about applying functions to a grouping of items is to define those "variables" as values in an array rather than defining them individually, that way you have access to methods like [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

E.g.

```js
const productPriceItems = [
  'Value 1',
  'Value 2',
  'Value 3'
];
```

So on and so forth. As a side note, `var element = {{product-price-item-1}}` is not valid JavaScript. It would do you good to brush up on basic [data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Comment: Sorry I’m not familiar with Javascript. Correct Update?

Comment: @vincents Your syntax looks similar to a templating languages' variable. If you are writing your JS inline in a `<script>` element with a templating variable, that may very be correct. If this is vanilla JS, though, you would assign a literal value like you would most any other language.

Comment: It’s GTM variables ;-)